# Broken buck converter investigation

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a LT3508 Dual DC/DC converter with 24V input and 12V and 3V3 output.

However some units are not working as intended, but provide the following waveforms on the 3V3 side:
[image]
Red = Boost, Green = 3V3 output, Blue = Switch node. The frequency is only about 600Hz.

Please find the schematic and waveforms of a working unit here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhpQf.jpg (I can only post two links)

Any idea what could be wrong or broken?

Comment: Over current protection/hick-up mode. Can you apply voltage to each rail separatly with a current limit? Does any rail consume more current than it should?

Comment: Check for solder bridges or cold solder joints.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: See page 13 "Boost pin considerations", where it says "if you are generating a 3.3V output, and the 3.3V output is on whenever the particular channel is on, the anode of the BOOST diode can be connected to the 3.3V output."

Comment: @Laurenz saw that after I commented.

Comment: @winny unfortunately my power supply can't limit current lower than 150mA. But the working unit draws 18mA at 24V, the broken one 16mA at 24V. The broken one's LT3508 does get warm after some time though.

Comment: You can't draw conclusions from the input in this state. Apply 3.3 V on the 3.3 V rail externally with a current limit and check which part heats up.

Comment: It may be marginally stable (component tolerance perhaps). I would try a 100pF capacitor across R3.

Comment: @winny both units draw 68mA at 3.3V. The onboard  microcontroller that the rail supplies is working correctly in both cases.

Comment: Good. Was the buck output connected while you applied 3.3 V and measured 68 mA?

Comment: @Peter Smith: I only had 100nF at hand. No effect :(
@ winny: yes.

Comment: You are *really* close to the minimum duty cycle; from your circuit, the operating frequency appears to be 1MHz. DC(min) is 130nS * F, which yields 0.13; the DC you have is about 0.15. 24V is also very close to the maximum for your setup (I get about 24.4V at low loads). See page 9 of the datasheet.

Comment: Then you have ruled out a short. With an unstable loop you should still see 3.3 V average unless your controller does something magically and that 500-600 Hz oscillation is farilt high to be hick-up and very low to be oscillation.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @PeterSmith. I changed R9 to 44k, which should yield around 800kHz switching frequency. I get nice 3V3 and 12V now :) http://i.imgur.com/42aSye8.png

Comment: @Laurenz: converted to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum input voltage and the minimum duty cycle for proper operation are determined in large part by the oscillator frequency.

The frequency you have chosen yields about 15.5% duty cycle vs. a minimum duty cycle (at 1MHz) of 13% (this is given by the minimum switch on time * the operating frequency - the higher the operating frequency, the higher the minimum duty cycle)

The maximum input is *inversely* proportional to the operating frequency, so a higher operating frequency yields a lower maximum Vin. The maximum input voltage at low loads for your circuit is about 24.4V (too close to the 24V you specify for comfort)

At input voltages above this, the output wanders:

[image: LT3508 with Vin too high]

Selecting a lower operating frequency will solve both issues.